# Is it possible to have "COMMON" variable for all clustered nodes in node js?

Tags: node.js

I am using clustering with NodeJS. What I want to do is "To access a common variable in all clustered nodes.." Just like a static variable in OOPS.
Can anyone have idea about this?

Comment: What do you mean by "static"? Do you want that variable to be read-only? Then simply define it in the master process. Clustering works by forking so it will be available in each child. But if you want to modify it then you'll probably want to use a shared "database" like shared memory or standalone database server (memcached, redis, mysql, etc.).

Comment: @freakish: I need to do both operations on it.

Comment: shared memory only works on a single machine, I suggest using a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, It is not possible to use common variable for clustered nodes. But as a work around, I used a `redis`server [as database query takes more time than redis query] to store/retrieve data.